# If my entire training set of documents is class A, how can I use TF-IDF to find other documents of class A?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tf-idf, text-classification

I have a collection X of documents, all of which are of class A (the only class in which I'm interested or know anything about). I also have a much larger collection Y of documents that I know nothing about. The documents in X and Y come from the same source and have similar formats and somewhat similar subject matters. I'd like to use the TF-IDF feature vectors of the documents in X to find the documents in Y that are most likely to be of class A.

In the past, I've used TF-IDF feature vectors to build naive Bayes classifiers, but in these situations, my training set X consisted of documents of many classes, and my objective was to classify each document in Y as one of the classes seen in X.

This seems like a different situation. Here, my entire training set has the same class (I have no documents that I know are not of class A), and I'm only interested in determining if documents in Y are or are not of that class.

A classifier seems like the wrong route, but I'm not sure what the best next step is. Is there a different algorithm that can use that TF-IDF matrix to determine the likelihood that a document is of the same class?

FYI, I'm using scikit-learn in Python 2.7, which obviously made computing the TF-IDF matrix of X (and Y) simple.

Comment: You could compute the similarity between the feature vectors of each document in Y and the aggregate feature vector of X.  If you then sorted by similarity, you could have an idea of the relative likelihood of X-membership.  But without any knowledge about the classes of Y and/or how they relate to X, you can't conclude much.  If the documents in Y are very similar to or different from each other or X, their similarities to X may not be very informative about their similarities to each other.

Comment: @BrenBarn, how would I go about aggregating the feature vectors of X into a single vector?

Comment: You could just sum them or average them.

Comment: I would give a try to *anomaly detection*. You would need to identify at least a few examples of documents that are NOT class A to validate and evaluate your model (but I guess you would need at least a few whatever technique you used). The point is that you can train the model with all examples of class A. There seems to be [an implementation in scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/outlier_detection.html) but I haven't used it myself. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I think you have is an unsupervised learning application.  Clustering.  Using the combined X & Y dataset, generate clusters.  Then overlay the X boundary; the boundary that contains all X samples.  All items from Y in the X boundary can be considered X.  And the X-ness of a given sample from Y is the distance from the X cluster centroid.  Something like that.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing to do is what was already proposed - clustering. More specifically, you extract a single feature vector from set X and then apply K-means clustering to the whole X & Y set.

ps: Be careful not to confuse k-means with kNN (k-nearest neighbors). You are able to apply only unsupervised learning methods.